# Julia `@kwdef` -- having "extra constructors"

Tags: julia

Suppose I have

```
@kwdef struct SomeParams
    A::Float64
    B::Float64
end
```

having moved from

```
struct SomeParams
    A::Float64
    B::Float64

    function SomeParams(C::Float64)
        new(C^2, C + 0.5)
    end
end
```

Is there a good way for me to have my cake and eat it too?

Leaving the constructor produces an error with the keyword args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not intefer with the other.
You could do:

```
@kwdef struct SomeParams
    A::Float64
    B::Float64
    SomeParams(C::Float64) = new(C^2, C + 0.5)
    SomeParams(A::Float64, B::Float64) = new(A, B)
end
```

And now just:

```
julia> SomeParams(3.0)
SomeParams(9.0, 3.5)

julia> SomeParams(;A=3.0, B=2.0)
SomeParams(3.0, 2.0)
```

To understand this behavior have a look at the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/):

> If any inner constructor method is defined, no default constructor method is provided: it is presumed that you have supplied yourself with all the inner constructors you need. The default constructor is equivalent to writing your own inner constructor method that takes all of the object's fields as parameters (constrained to be of the correct type, if the corresponding field has a type), and passes them to new, returning the resulting object

Hence if you overwrite the inner constructor you need to provide the default implementation too.

#### EDIT

Of course it is always possible to keep the constructor outside the object as you can see in the other answer.

Comment: Edit -- just realized the line it was complaining about was the next struct, not the first kwdef I have like this in the file. I have exactly your first suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/fb7613635cab77cf269790335e8121f513c9ea96/base/util.jl#L530), (emphasis mine)

> This is a helper macro that automatically defines a keyword-based constructor for the type
> declared in the expression `typedef`, which must be a `struct` or `mutable struct`
> expression. The default argument is supplied by declaring fields of the form `field::T = default` or `field = default`. If no default is provided then the keyword argument becomes
> a required keyword argument in the resulting type constructor.
>
> Inner constructors can still be defined, but **at least one should accept arguments in the
> same form as the default inner constructor** (i.e. one positional argument per field) in
> order to function correctly with the keyword outer constructor.

So if you want to define inner constructors, you need to define a version that's compatible with the outer one generated by `@kwdef`.

If you're just delegating to the `@kwdef` constructor, though, you can write an outer constructor and avoid the whole problem.

```
@kwdef struct SomeParams
    A::Float64
    B::Float64
end

SomeParams(C::Float64) = SomeParams(A=C^2, B=C + 0.5)
```